# How to propagate uncertainties for parameters whose upper and lower uncertainties are different?

Tags: sampling, error-propagation

If $A = A_0 \pm \sigma_A$, $B = B_0 \pm \sigma_B$, and $f = \frac{A}{B}$, the normal error propagation goes like ([following Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#cite_ref-13))
\begin{equation}
  \sigma_f = \sqrt{\sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2 - 2\sigma_{AB}}
\end{equation}

How to propagate the uncertainties for parameters whose upper and lower uncertainties are different? For example, when we use some sampling method, such as MCMC, we might get variables that look like $A = 32.0_{-0.3}^{+0.5}$ and $B = 17.0_{-0.2}^{+1.3}$. How to generalize error propagation to such cases? Do we simply adopt the larger uncertainties ($\sigma_A = 0.5$ and $\sigma_B = 1.3$)? Or does $\sigma_A = (A_{\rm 84th} - A_{\rm 16th})/2$, which is half of the width of the $68$% confidence interval?

Edit:

As @whuber asked in the comment, the upper uncertainty corresponds to the 84th percentile of the sampling and the lower uncertainty corresponds to the 16th percentile.

Comment: In order to make progress, you need to explain what these "uncertainties" are and how they have been calculated or estimated.

Comment: @whuber In my case, the uncertainties comes from MCMC sampling. They are 16th, 50th, and 84th percentiles of the samples in the
marginalized distributions, as described in the [last paragraph of this emcee documentation page](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/line/).

Comment: That suggests you might have the opportunity to collect much more detailed information about these estimates and then use it to propagate uncertainties.  Is there some obstacle to doing that?

Comment: If $a = A_{\rm 84th} - A_{\rm 50th} = A_{\rm 50th} - A_{\rm 16th}$, then I will just set $\sigma_A = a$. But, in the case when $ A_{\rm 84th} - A_{\rm 50th} \ne A_{\rm 50th} - A_{\rm 16th}$, I feel confused which number should be to $\sigma_A$.

Comment: Neither.  It would help to collect the more detailed information I described.

Comment: Sorry, I feel unsure how to follow what you said. Should I use the sampling result to recalculate the mean and standard deviation and use the standard deviation as $\sigma_A$?

Comment: @whuber I have an idea about doing the propagation: Because I have a full knowledge of the PDFs of the parameters, I can do a sampling of the function I need (i.e., $f(A, B)$) by drawing parameters from the MCMC result and use the 16-50-84 percentile of $f(A, B)$ to find the uncertainties. I would appreciate if you can elaborate what you mean by "collect much more detailed information about these estimates and then use it to propagate uncertainties." I have though about it, but to do the propagation technically is really difficult ([this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0306138.pdf)).

Comment: @Consideration hi i am facing the same issue. can you share how did you solve it?